# Как вернуть .kv-код в .py?

Tags: python, kivy

В первый раз решил использовать kv-файл для kivymd, но вот как использовать вместе с Python не знаю, пытался прописать так, но содержимое .kv неотображается - 
.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Example",type="custom",content_cls=Content(),
            buttons=[MDFlatButton(text="CANCEL", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color),
            MDFlatButton(text="OK", text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color)])
        self.dialog.open()
Example().run()
```

.kv:

```
#import MDTextField kivymd.textfields.MDTextField
<Content>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: .5
    height: "100dp"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Введите имя"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KV файл нужно загружать в код так:

```
KV = """
...
...
"""

Builder.load_string(KV)
```

Или

```
Builder.load_file(path_to_kv)
```

Здесь подробнее - https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html
И не нужно делать импорты в KV файле виджетов KivyMD - это ошибка.

Comment: Ооо, да, то что нужно

Comment: Можете подсказать как использовать текст из MDText_Field в классе Example, если в считать KV ="""<Content>...""" уже в в коде .py? Т.е. как-то забирать его из класса Content. Я в этом дуб дубом, всегда только одним классом пользовался

Comment: https://python-scripts.com/question/10909